# Redirect domain to another domain same subfolder structure

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect domain to another domain and same subfolder structure

for example :-

```
http://www.domain.com/forum
```

will be redirect to

```
http://www.domain.net/forum
```

thanks

Comment: Note: you almost certainly want to use a *permanent* redirect and not just a typical redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.org$ 
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://domain.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You need to make sure that the follow is enabled also - "RewriteEngine On" and "AllowOverride all"